# FB PHP SDK and mod_rewrite: getUser returns 0

Tags: mod-rewrite, facebook-php-sdk

I am using the Facebook PHP SDK in order to allow users to log in to my site using Facebook.
In my test below (assume the URL is http://mysite.com/test/fbtest.php),

```php
<?php
    require_once("facebook.php");
    $fb = new Facebook(array('appId' => 'APP_ID', 'secret' => 'APP_SECRET'));
    $fbuser = false;
    $fbuserid = $fb->getUser();
    $fblogin = $fb->getLoginUrl(array(
        'redirect_uri' => "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/test/fbtest.php"));

if($fbuserid)
{
    try
    {
        $fbuser = $fb->api("/me");
        print_r($fbuser);
        echo "<br/>\n";
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e)
    {
        $fbuser = false;
        $fbuserid = 0;
    }
}
if(!$fbuser)
    echo "<a href=\"$fblogin\">FB Login</a>\n";
?>
```

This seems to work as expected. However, when I add the following rewrite rule,

```
RewriteRule ^/FBtest/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/test/fbtest.php$1
```

Then change my login redirect to the following,

```php
$fblogin = $fb->getLoginUrl(array(
        'redirect_uri' => "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/FBtest/"));
```

Then `$fb->getUser()` always returns 0. I feel that I am missing something important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured this problem out. Here is the RewriteRule I need:

```
RewriteRule ^/FBtest/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/test/fbtest.php [QSA,NE]
```

It turns out I needed to add both the QSA and NE flags to this rule.

Much like in CBroe's answer, the QSA flag was needed for the state/code parameters added to redirect_uri (using `(.*)` within the RewriteRule instead doesn't catch these additional parameters).

I also needed to add the NE flag because the state/code that the Facebook authentication was adding to the redirect_uri was being escaped.

Answer (score 1):

In the server side flow, your redirect_uri get’s called with the necessary values as GET parameters in the query string.

> `'redirect_uri' => "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/FBtest/"`

So with this redirect_uri, something like

```
http://example.com/FBtest/?state=foo&code=bar
```

will be called on your server.

> `RewriteRule ^/FBtest/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/test/fbtest.php$1`

RewriteRules don’t examine the query string, they only look at the *path* component of the URL. In your case, that’s `/FBtest/`, nothing behind it – so the internal redirect goes to `/test/fbtest.php`, and the query string parameters get lost, because you didn’t say you wanted to pass them on.

Add the flag `[QSA]` – for “query string append” – to your RewriteRule (and remove the unnecessary `(.*)`) – then things should work as expected, because your fbtest.php will get the query string parameters needed for the auth process.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was unaware of the `[QSA]` flag, and I thought the `(.*)` would catch any GET parameters added to the redirect_uri and append them as needed. Unfortunately, I have made these changes and my problem still persists.

Comment: Well, then generate some debug output from your script (var_dump of $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE …) – and compare that between both ways of calling the script. Any significant differences …?

Comment: I do see something. In the redirect test, $_SESSION is empty. In the successful test it contains the code, access_token, and user_id parameters. $_GET and PHPSESSID are passed correctly in both tests.

Comment: For what path is your session cookie set?

Comment: Hm, then I don’t know any more (not easy debugging “remote”). Anyways, also print out the session id and the $_COOKIE contents before and after logging in – an empty session clearly points in the direction of the session id not being transfered correctly.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep that in mind as I research this further. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: One more thought: Try giving the target of your rewrite not as a _full_ URL, but only as `/test/fbtest.php [QSA]` (or whatever path fits from the directory where you’re doing your rewrite) …

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to use any other domain other than the domain you set in your applications settings.

"be sure you are using the root domain, and not sample.com/test/ as your url settings."

Comment: HTTP_HOST is most likely the _same_ domain.

Comment: I believe Facebook usually redirects to an error page if you try to auth from an unspecified domain.